# Problematic Mail Sieve rules

Tags: email, dovecot, regex, regular-expressions, sieve

I need top classify my incomming emails using this three rules:

1. if the email was send to **any** @somedomain.tld, then copy that email to "somedomain_tld"
2. if the email was send to **any other** @*.tld , then copy that email to "others_tlds". (any other = "not somedomain.tld")
3. The rest of emails, copy to a third folder "rest".

I'm using dovecot sieve rules to do this.

There is an additional condition: the three rules above must be applied to every "To:" address in the email... So in the most complex case, the email should be copied in the three folders

for example: the following email should be copied to the three folders:

```
From: user@someunrelateddomain.anytld
To: myaddress@mydomain.mytld, user@otherdomain.tld, user@somedomain.tld
Subject: Test Email

This is a test email
```

1. Because of "user@somedomain.tld" this email should be copied to "somedomain_tld"
2. Because of "user@otherdomain.tld" this email should be copied to "others_tlds"
3. Because of "myaddress@mydomain.mytld" this email should be copied to "rest"

The require and the first rule is easy:

```
require ["fileinto","copy"];
if address :is :domain "to" "somedomain.tld" { fileinto :copy "somedomain_tld"; }
```

but the second don't know how to do it:

```
if address :matches :domain "to" "*.tld" { fileinto :copy "others_tlds"; }
```

will match somedomain.tld also, which is not what is intended... (if I have an email with "To: user@somedomain.tld" it will be copied to somedomain_tld (OK) and others_tlds (BUG))

For #3 I don't have a clue.

I was also thinking of regexes, but I don know how to express "every domain except this" in a sieve regex (or any other regex style)

Does anyone knows how to bends dovecot's sieve to do 1,2,3?

Answer (score 1):

```
require ["fileinto"];
if header :contains "To" "domain.tld"
{
        fileinto "INBOX/domain_tld";
        stop;
}
if header :contains "To" ".tld"
{
        fileinto "INBOX/other_tld";
        stop;
}
if true
{
        fileinto "INBOX/rest";
        stop;
}
```